# A conditional statement checking for null not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, null

I have a variable named `header` that is `null` and `typeof header` shows `string`. But, it doesn't meet any of the following condition:

```js
        const header = request.request ? request.request.headers.authorization : request.connection.context.Authorization
        if(header == '' || header == null || header == undefined || header == false || header == 0 || header == NaN || !!header) {
            console.log("Condition met")    
        }
```

It doesn't seem like there any more way to qualify `null`. What's happening?

Comment: also it's better practice to use `===` (strict check) as the equals operator instead of  `==` (loose check).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its `typeof` is `string`, and it contains `null`, then it's the string `'null'`. Add:

```
if (header === 'null' || ...
```

Comment: Thats not true, actually - he didnt use typeof anywhere in his code sample

Comment: @kinduser in OP's post he said `typeof header` shows `string`...

Comment: @kinduser not in the code sample, in the first sentence of the post. He says he ran `typeof header` and it was `string`

Comment: @MikeAbeln yet still it doesnt make any sense, header variable is just some response from probably async request, why would he even mention that typeof it returns a string even if he expects it to be e.g. boolean or number...